# Using Apache mod_rewrite to redirect to static content if exists

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

#### Background

I'm optimizing some highly trafficked pages by creating a static cache. As the content doesn't change often, the mechanism to generate and invalidate the cache was straightforward. Currently though, I'm accessing the cache via PHP (basic `file_exists()` check). I'd like to bring this up to the web server level to cut PHP out entirely.

#### Spec

I will have thousands of cached pages. So the directory tree I envision is:

```
year -> first id of digit -> second id of digit -> id.html
```

I'm splitting it out this way to avoid ten's thousands of files in a single directory - as I understand that's a performance hit. I'm familiar with mod_rewrite, but not quite sure how to capture the necessary pieces of the URL and determine if the file exists.

Here's an example of the incoming URL:

```
/2011/37823/some_slug
```

Some pseudo code, using the URL above:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} ^(\d{4})/...
RewriteCond /cache/$1/$3/$4/$2.html -f
RewriteRule - /cache/$1/$3/$4/$2.html [L]
```

#### Questions

- How can I create the `RewriteRule`'s for the above?
- Is there a better way to do this (using the technologies of the LAMP stack)?

Comment: I have never used it, but I vaguely remember there being a mod_cache.  Or have you already looked into that?

Comment: Have not, but I will. Unfortunately at the moment, I'm on a shared hosting environment. So even it if did apply, I may not be able to use it. In the meantime, I am sure there's a way to do it with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Ah, on shared hosting I doubt it will be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will need tweaking as your regex doesn't match the pattern you list (the order changes) but the following is based on your example URL:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1$2$3\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(\d+)(/\d+)(/[^/]+)$ /cache/$1$2$3.html [L]
```

If you want a bit more nesting (folders based on first and second digit of IDs, but ignore the rest of the middle part of the URL) then it'd be:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1$2/$3$4\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(\d+)(/\d)(\d)\d*(/[^/]+)$ /cache/$1$2/$3$4.html [L]
```

The RewriteRule is checked first to see if the rule applies. The `RewriteCond` then checks the file exists (`DOCUMENT_ROOT` is the site root) using the captures from the `RewriteRule`. If this exists then the conditions are met and the `RewriteRule` rewrites the URL, serving the cached page before stopping trying to rewrite `[L]`.

In terms of better options, this is better than the PHP you have as it won't start PHP for cached pages. It will, however, check the pattern for every resource request.

Comment: True about the pattern check for every request. I'm curious on your take. I assume if I put this as one of my last rules, I could mitigate the issue.

Comment: You've got to check something on every request if you want to check a cache. This is a (hopefully quite tight but simple) regex and a file system check, which isn't terrible. I think ordering depends on how often it will occur. If 90% of requests will be cached then put this near the top as it has `[L]` to stop further processing. If 1% of content will be cached then put any other `[L]` rules that happen more often before it.

Answer (score 0):

This, I think, should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\d{4})\/((\d)(\d)\d+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%1/%3/%4/%2.html -f
RewriteRule ^.* /cache/%1/%3/%4/%2.html [L,QSA]
```

The first condition matches /(YEAR)/((digit1)(digit2)digit3-to-n). The parantheses tells the system to store the values inside to variables %1-%4. Please note the tricky part where there is parantheses within parantheses. It seems like regexp count the order from the start/open paranthese, so the outer `(` around the id will be %2 and then digit1 is %3 and so on

The second condition checks for the complete file path. DOCUMENT_ROOT gives you the local filesystem path. Please note I'm using `%`and not `$`. This is because I use the stored variables from the **previous** line and not the current.

The RewriteRule just rewrites everything to your new path. The [L] tells apache to stop looking for more rewrites and [QSA] (Query String Append) puts back the querystring after the rewrite (Not sure if you needed that).

Comment: Can you explain your `RewriteRule` more? I want to learn. Specifically, why is this different than **IBBoard**'s answer?

Comment: This did not work for me. I imagine it was something I missed. In the end, the other answer worked and is more intuitive to me.